# Instantiate a class which implements a generic interface

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an interface for specifying GetData method which returns one instance of the class by its ID

```
public interface ILabelData<T> {
  T GetData(object id);
}
```

and also have many different classes those who implements the interface and having members of course:

```
public class BTAC : ILabelData<BTAC> {
  // members...
  // and interface impl:
  public BTAC GetData(object id) {
    return null;
  }
}
public class KTAC : ILabelData<KTAC> {
  // members...
  // and interface impl:
  public KTAC GetData(object id) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Within a calling method I would like to instantiate a BTAC/KTAC/... class and call their GetData method. (The purpose of it is becasue after I have the required  instance I want to get its members and attributes. Getting the members and attributes is not part of my question.)

```
ILabelData<object> o = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { myID });
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
object data = o.GetData(myID);
```

the problem is compiler error **Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'ILabelData< object >'**

After instantiating the proper class of course I do need for the members and attributes, too, so it isn't enough to getting back ILabelData typed object.

How can I get a such kind of object? Some factory or whatever?

Comment: `CreateInstance` works on a single instance of a single type. It doesn't create an array of objects, but a single one. More over, it returns an `object`.

Comment: @haim770 But it isn't a `List`, it's a single instance of a type.

Comment: @haim770 Not really - the type he's trying to get does not implement `ILabelData<object>`, it implements `ILabelData<BTAC>` or `ILabelData<KTAC>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're mixing up the factory and the entity. That's unnecessary - it really doesn't make sense to have `GetData` be an instance method on `BTAC`.
2. `Activator.CreateInstance` returns `object` - you need to explicitly cast it to the type you want.
3. Neither of your types implements `ILabelData<object>`.

The thing is, with the code as is, there's no point in having `ILabelData` generic at all! If you're going to work with `object` anyway, remove the generic parameter from `ILabelData` and just do this:

```
var o = (ILabelData)Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { myID });

var data = o.GetData(myID);
```

Having the interface (and `GetData` method) generic only makes sense *if you actually use it that way*.

If you *usually* use it directly, and you only need it like this in a few special cases (why?) you could also make the interface covariant:

```
public interface ILabelData<out T>
{
  T GetData(object id);
}
```

This will allow you to implement `ILabelData<BTAC>` in `BTAC`, giving you the "user friendly" `BTAC GetData(object)` method, while still allowing you to do the explicit cast to `ILabelData<object>`. Even then, I'd avoid this approach. It smells.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I don't need generic interface

Answer (score 0):

Working Code here.

```
var instances = (from t in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes()
                        where t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILabelData<>))
                                 && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                        select Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();

        foreach (dynamic item in instances)
        {
            var res = item.GetData(1);
        }
```